# MenuItem Background opacity but not its text?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, menuitem

How do I set the background opacity of a menuitem to 0.0 but still appear its text with 1.0 opacity?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673132/wpf-contextmenu-design-how-to-set-background-in-wpf-menuitem

Answer (score 3):

To do this you need to set the background color to be one with no alpha channel (the first two digits in a hex color 0x00000000). This will make the background color fully transparent. Then, your text just needs to be any color with 0xFF for the alpha channel (the default).

Answer (score 3):

See this question: [WPF Transparent menu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4029917/302677)

You need to overwrite the MenuItem Template. Copy/Paste this into your `Window.Resources` or `Menu.Resources`

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Border Name="Border" >
      <Grid>
        <ContentPresenter 
          Margin="6,3,6,3" 
          ContentSource="Header"
          RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
        <Popup 
          Name="Popup"
          Placement="Bottom"
          IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}"
          AllowsTransparency="True" 
          Focusable="False"
          PopupAnimation="Fade">
          <Border 
            Name="SubmenuBorder"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
            Background="Transparent">
            <StackPanel  
              IsItemsHost="True" 
              KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
          </Border>
        </Popup>
      </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
        <Setter TargetName="Popup" Property="PopupAnimation" Value="None"/>
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#C0C0C0"/>
        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0,0,4,4"/>
        <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,3"/>
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
      </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
  </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Rachel, I'm using this example, but if the menuitem has children they are not painted in the same way, can't figure out how to get that right.  Copied the above and set it  x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey}" but the formatting is not correct